# Wordpress API - Ionic GET - The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *'

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework, cors, http-headers

I am currently building some custom API's using WordPress API,
and works great as calling from browser as this link:

https://laundrylocker-eg.com/wp-json/wp/v2/delivery-locations

The response in JSON nothing goes wrong,
so from Ionic application I try to call this API to get callback this data but faced this CORS issue and try to fix it. Nothing works like disable CORS in Chrome and using plugin enabling CORS for all domains as development phase.

[image: CORS PLUGIN IMG]

[image: CONSOLE ERROR]

> Failed to load https://laundrylocker-eg.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pickup-locations/2018-04-03: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
> core.js:1350 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}

[image: REQUEST INFORMATION]

> Request URL: https://laundrylocker-eg.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pickup-locations/2018-04-03
> Request Method: OPTIONS
> Status Code: 200 OK
> Remote Address: 50.87.248.230:443
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, Content-Range,
> Content-Disposition, Content-Description, Access-Control-Request-Method
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
> Allow: GET
> Cache-Control: max-age=21600
> Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Encoding: gzip
> Content-Length: 116
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
> Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2018 12:02:28 GMT
> Expires: Tue, 03 Apr 2018 18:02:28 GMT
> Link: https://laundrylocker-eg.com/wp-json/; rel="https://api.w.org/"
> Server: nginx/1.12.2

Comment: did you try with advanced HTTP plugin ?

Comment: @CodeChanger u mean plugin for wordpress or ionic ?!

Comment: Do you have any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` language in your api code?

Comment: what u actually mean with acc-control.... language ?!

Answer (score 0):

It's not that you are returning a single ACAO header with a value of `*, *` - it's that you are returning duplicate CORS headers, and the browser has merged them.

Somewhere in your code (or in the code of the packages you're using), the CORS headers are being added twice. My *guess* is that you have somehow added two CORS-enablement packages or something like that, and they're both adding CORS response headers...

Since the value of the two `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers are different, it should be easy enough to search for where they are being added and remove the duplication.